# Can value types be implemented by inlining?

Tags: c#, jvm, language-design, value-type, vm-implementation

When I first saw the value types in C#, the first thing I thought was "wow, what a great optimization", the second thing is, "do we really need a new language construct? can't we do that with annotations instead?".

The idea is, given a class, we'll use it as we always did

```
class A {int i;}
class B {
    A m_a;
    int F(A a) {m_a = a;}
}
```

On a whim we'll change `A` to be

```
[ValueType]
class A {int i;int j;}
```

And the compiler will automatically convert class `B` to be

```
class B {
#region A
    int A_i;
    int A_j;
#endregion
int F(/*A param*/int i,int j) {
#region A_assign
    A_i = i;
    A_j = j;
#endregion
}
```

Bear in mind, that if the compiler doesn't wish to optimize some instance - it doesn't have to. It would work either way.

It might arise problems with templates,

```
int f<T>() {
    T t; // how much stack should I allocate
}
```

but I'm not sure it's much worse than the current situation. I'm actually not sure what happens now (is `f<struct_of_100_bytes>` a different function than `f<int>`?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now imagine inheritance. Or arrays. Or arguments. Or generics. Or implementing an interface. Or assigning to object/dynamic.

And keep in mind that the runtime supports multiple compilers.

Having a specific keyword (struct) rather than an attribute is not really a big change (indeed, in terms of the CLI everything is called a class), but the overall situation is much more complex than your example.

Basically, struct does pretty-much everything you mention, and works in all the scenarios listed. Since it generally (for locals) uses the stack, it already behaves much like you describe.

Re the "separate function" question; firstly, generics are not "templates" (it is runtime vs compile-time). But generics get a JIT per value-type, and a single JIT per reference-type (because indeed: the stack layout changes.

Comment: You can always fall back to regular object (you made a really messy object? No inlining for you). And I don't really see (as in don't understand, not as in disagree) how inheritance (C++ does value type inheritance), or arrays, or arguments, or generics, or implementing an interface interfere with inlining, it seems possible in all three cases. Can you please expand on that? Maybe an example will help.

Comment: @Elazar in the case of passing an interface as a parameter, for example, it simply makes no sense - the caller won't know what to do. But in the general case, this is pretty similar to how structs works anyway. Not sure what the point is here

Comment: Oh, I get it. When passing a struct that implements an interface as a function argument. (In that case, indeed I meant to fallback.) Thanks. Another question I had is, I heard that the VM itself support value types, and it seems possible with the compiler cooperation alone.

Comment: @Elazar yes, but that would impact interop - as each compiler might do it a different way. I like letting the JIT define the rules here. Also - encapsulation and accessibility is a big issue here.